# Integrating Octave interpreter into program compiled with GCC 4.8.1

Tags: windows, c++11, octave, embedding, gcc4.8

I'm trying to integrate Octave interpreter into my rigid body simulator compiled with GCC 4.8.1. 
Following steps posted in the official documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html) allow me to compile, link, and successfully execute the first example. Note, that I can link the executable with both mkoctfile.exe, or g++ when minGW 4.8.1 is added to PATH.
However, the second example showing how to embed the interpreter into my program compiles, links, and then segfaults on execution when GCC 4.8.1 binaries are in PATH. It works, when I use the supplied compiler (in my case it's gcc 4.6.2 shipped with octave 3.6.1 on windows).

Do I need to build octave from source using GCC 4.8.1 in order to successfully link program compiled using that version, or is there any other way to do so?

Using GCC 4.6.2 is not an option for me, as my program uses c++11 features not present in that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that there is a newer Octave version available at http://mxeoctave.osuv.de/ which was compiled with GCC 4.9.2. This version of GCC works for me perfectly and the second example provided in the documentation started to work when compiled with g++ provided with the distribution.